# Can jPlayer do live RTMP streaming yet?

Tags: javascript, video, jplayer

I'm working on a website for a podcast that does live video and audio streaming. We're currently stuck using JWPlayer AND jPlayer to do it.

The reason is that past attempts to get jPlayer to play *live* RTMP streams have never seemed to work. Live audio on the other hand works fine though.

I've seen plenty of demos for RTMP video streaming, but they're streaming a static, prerecorded file, not a live feed.

Here's a sample stream I'm trying to use: rtmp://pclix-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/pclix-channel/live/mp4:priestly (we're using ScaleEngine, so if it works with this it'll work with ours).

It won't seem to play at all. No errors in console that I can find, nothing.

I can't find any recent information saying one way or another if it's even currently able to support it. So I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if it's currently futile and I should just find another free, open-source solution (we don't want JWPlayer). All we need is a player composed of a video window and a JavaScript API; we already have a custom CSS skin for it.